# Are there any good tutorials on building an ecommerce website with code igniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to learn a new framework in PHP and would like to see if Code Igniter will be able to support ecommerce checkouts, shopping carts, purchases and, on the seller side, purchase orders.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are a few:

- [Building a Basic PHP E-Commerce Application Using CodeIgniter](http://blog.insicdesigns.com/2009/02/building-a-basic-php-e-commerce-application-using-codeigniter-framework-part-1/)
- [How to Build a Shopping Cart using CodeIgniter and jQuery](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-build-a-shopping-cart-using-codeigniter-and-jquery/)
- [Codeigniter shopping cart v1.1](http://www.okadadesign.no/blog/codeigniter/codeigniter-shopping-cart-updates-part-1/)
- [Building a simple PHP shopping cart](http://v3.thewatchmakerproject.com/journal/276/building-a-simple-php-shopping-cart)
- [CodeIgniter Shopping Cart Library](http://www.reloadedpc.com/code-igniter/codeigniter-shopping-cart-library/)